# in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods'

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

after running this command npx react-native run-ios I got the following error

objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gdeqobulqkaquxebjscszekkbgtp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ImagePickerManager.o /Users/ryoh/Desktop/myapp-main/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/ios/ImagePickerManager.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

I'll be happy for your help

Thank you!

Comment: Did you `pod install`?

Comment: @devpolo yes sure, but It still not work

Answer (score 0):

try to run your app again after the cmd : RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, downgrade the `react-native-image-picker` to version 4.0.6:

```
npm uninstall react-native-image-picker
npm install react-native-image-picker@4.0.6
```

This solved here